# What is this encoding and how to I convert it?

Tags: python, string, xpath, encoding, format

I am pulling text out from an html tag attribute using lxml and xpath via `tag.attrib['title']`. I get:

```
MÃ¡laga Airport
```

where in the browser with the same url I am seeing:

```
Málaga Airport
```

How do I convert the former to the later?

Comment: What does "pulling text out" mean? Please edit to post what you're actually doing to "pull text out". It's pretty hard to say what the problem is if you don't show us what you're doing in the first place.

Comment: tag.attrib['title'] gives me the text of 'an html tag attribute' in lxml.

Comment: a single non-latin1 character becoming two characters,happens usually when you have utf-8 and interpret it as latin1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the lxml html parser assumes a 'latin1' encoding for byte strings.

So unless the input is encoded as 'latin1' (or 'ascii'), the encoding needs to be specified explicitly. In this case, it looks like it should be 'utf-8':

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> html = u"""
... <html>
... <head><title>Test</title></head>
... <body>
... <p test="Málaga">Example</p>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>>
>>> html = html.encode('utf-8')
>>>
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(html, parser)
>>> print tree.xpath('//p/@test')[0]
MÃ¡laga
>>>
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(html, parser)
>>> print tree.xpath('//p/@test')[0]
Málaga
```